# how can i get the last incremented value in shell script?

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the last incremented value of variable count but every time it prints
0 that is the initial value, how can I get the last incremented value of variable count.

```
 count=0

 mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT Department FROM
 entrytests_datetime WHERE Discipline='msc'" | while read department
 do

    echo "V,department_$count=$department"
    let "count++"
 done

 echo "V,count=$count"

 echo "E,resume"
```

Comment: In the newest versions of `bash` (4.2 or later), you can add `shopt -s lastpipe` to the beginning of the script to solve the problem described in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because piped while loop creates a sub-shell and a child process cannot change parent's environment. Try this instead:

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash

 count=0

 while read department
 do
    echo "V,department_$count=$department"
    let "count++"
 done < <(mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute \
      "SELECT Department FROM entrytests_datetime WHERE Discipline='msc'")

 echo "V,count=$count"

 echo "E,resume"
```

I have to say, this is not Posix compliant. Test it by setting `set -o posix` in bash, and seeing the error.

Comment: No, I *don't*. I mean you have to say it uses non-POSIX extension. Not all shells have it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the loop is executed in a subshell and values are not (and cannot be) propagated to the parent shell. It is executed in a subshell because commands in a pipeline have to be. You have two options:

1. Print the value inside the subshell
2. Make the loop run in the main shell

The first option is easy using only POSIX shell constructs. Simply wrap the loop with the final echo in curly braces:

```
count=0
mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT Department FROM
    entrytests_datetime WHERE Discipline='msc'" | {
    while read department; do
        echo "V,department_$count=$department"
        let "count++"
    done
    echo "V,count=$count"
    echo "E,resume"
}
```

Since the script seems to end there, this should be viable. For the second option I can only see a way in shell that supports *process substitution **extension*** e.g. bash:

```
count=0
while read department; do
    echo "V,department_$count=$department"
   let "count++"
done < <(mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT Department
    FROM entrytests_datetime WHERE Discipline='msc'")
echo "V,count=$count"
echo "E,resume"
```

I would recommend *against* writing scripts in bash; many systems now use simpler shell as `/bin/sh` for performance reasons and these shells often don't support the process substitution extension.